# Unexpected app crashing

Tags: ios, crash

When I build my app through xcode, it always crashes when I press the button linked to starttimer:. It highlights the last curly bracket in the code. It is important to note that when I launch the app through the simulator, I am able to click the button without a crash. What's happening? Here's some code:

```
@implementation TimeController

int timeTick = 0;


NSTimer *timer;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    labelTime.text = @"0";
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)startTimer:(id)sender {
    [timer invalidate];
    timer= [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:(self) selector:(@selector(tick)) userInfo:(nil) repeats:(YES)];
}

- (IBAction)resetTicktock:(id)sender {
    [timer invalidate];
    timeTick=0;
    labelTime.text = @"0";
}

-(void)tick{
    timeTick++;
    NSString *timeString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", timeTick];
    labelTime.text = timeString;
}




@end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the error / exception that causes crashing?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor This is the weird part. There is no error being shown. There is nothing displayed in the console.

Comment: Are you using ARC configured in your project?

Comment: Try cleaning your project before you build it, maybe you had a breakpoint set somewhere close by, which got shifted around... (Does it really crash, or simply break?)

Comment: Furthermore, you don't need the () in the     timer= [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:
 line....  just make it target:self selector:@selector(tick) userInfo:nil repeats:YES

Comment: @San I don't believe so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need () when calling a method.

Instead of

```
timer= [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:(self) selector:(@selector(tick)) userInfo:(nil) repeats:(YES)];
```

You should have

```
timer= [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(tick) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Comment: Yes. For whatever reason, this fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Whatever = Objective-C syntax ;) In Obj-C you don't use () to send parameters to your functions (as you would in Java/C++), instead you simply use : , which does the same. I just find it very awkward that the simulator wasn't crashing on this. It just goes on to show that the simulator doesn't always simulate things as it should ;)